# Plot two functions in the same plot with different vertical axes, colors, and labels

Tags: plotting, customization

I would like to plot two continuous functions in the same plot, but to each one should correspond a different vertical axis with different values, but having in common the same x axis. I would like also to choose the color of each function. I found this code

```
TwoAxisListPlot[{f_, g_}, opts___] := 
 Module[{fgraph, ggraph, frange, grange, fticks, 
   gticks}, {fgraph, ggraph} = 
   MapIndexed[
    ListPlot[#, Axes -> True, PlotStyle -> ColorData[1][#2[[1]]], 
      opts] &, {f, g}]; {frange, 
    grange} = (PlotRange /. 
        AbsoluteOptions[#, PlotRange])[[2]] & /@ {fgraph, ggraph};
  fticks = N@FindDivisions[frange, 10];
  gticks = 
   Quiet@Transpose@{fticks, 
      ToString[NumberForm[#, 2], StandardForm] & /@ 
       Rescale[fticks, frange, grange]};
  Show[fgraph, 
   ggraph /. 
    Graphics[graph_, s___] :> 
     Graphics[
      GeometricTransformation[graph, 
       RescalingTransform[{{0, 1}, grange}, {{0, 1}, frange}]], s], 
   Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> {ColorData[1] /@ {1, 2}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{fticks, gticks}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
   ImageSize -> 800]]
```

which is valid if the function f and g are a list of points. If I use the following functions

```
funcf = Table[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi, Pi/100}];
funcg = Table[Cos[x], {x, 0, Pi, Pi/100}];
```

in the above code

```
TwoAxisListPlot[{funcf, funcg}, {Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Black, Black}}, 
  ColorFunction -> {Black, Red}, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> Large, 
  FrameLabel -> {{"Mean magnetic field (T)", "(Hz)"}, {"\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"Some\",\nFontColor->GrayLevel[0]]\)\!\(\*
StyleBox[\" \",\nFontColor->GrayLevel[0]]\)\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"parameter\",\nFontColor->GrayLevel[0]]\)", ""}}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20}}]
```

I obtain

[image]

I would like to implement directly the functions funcf and funcg defined together with the range where they are defined. Indeed in the attached figure the x axis does not corresponds to the range [0,Pi]. In addition, I would like also to choose the colors of the two functions from the command option (for example one black and the other one red).

Comment: See [How to | Generate Plots with Two Vertical Scales](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/GeneratePlotsWithTwoVerticalScales.html). I believe that's the original code that was adapted to make `TwoAxisListPlot`.